# ACT math problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There's a certain type of math problem I've seen on the ACT that I don't know how to do and unfortunately I don't know if there's a name for it. One example I remember asked when two people will take their medications at the same time when they take their medication at different time intervals. Is there a name for this type of problem and does anyone know where I can find examples of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to **common multiple**.

Suppose a patient take medicine every $3$ hours and another take medicine every $4$ hours, when will they take medicine at the same time.

Answer would be multiple of $12$ assuming they begin to take medicine at the same time. $12$ is the least common multiple of $3$ and $4$.